# Angular 2/4 compile using AoT error - extendStatics

Tags: angular, angular-compiler-cli, angular-aot

I have an application which I'm trying to compile using AoT. When I build the application I'm getting the following error:

> C:\test\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\diagnostics\expression_diagnostics.js:14
>
> extendStatics(d, b);
>
> ^ TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

I know there are certain things that work with JIT compilation that don't with AoT, so my suspicion is I might have something in my code might not work with AoT. Any idea what could be the cause of this error please?

**Angular and TypeScript Version**

- Angular Version: 4.0.1
- Angular Compiler CLI: 4.2.5
- TypeScript: 2.3.4

Comment: Could please post which versions of angular and typescript you are using?

Comment: Sure thing, I updated the question

Comment: Okay so I realised that the @angular packages should be the same versions, so I'm updating all of them. I think it should solve the issue